# Generate standardised log-normal data in R

Tags: r, random, statistics, probability-distribution

I want to generate data from a log-normal distribution, with mean zero and variance equal to 1, in R.

I have tried this so far:

```r
(rlnorm(n = 100000, mean = 0, sdlog = 1) - exp(1/2))/(exp(1)*(exp(1)-1))
```

Using the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Arithmetic_moments), to get the mean and variance on the standard scale. I think that I have centred correctly, as when I calculate the sample mean for this generated data I get a value close to zero. However, the sample variance is not close to 1.

Comment: The mean specified in the log-normal distribution is the mean of the normal distribution with the same location and scale parameters before the exponential transformation. Try `x <- log(rlnorm(1e6, 0, 1)); mean(x); var(x)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can just use the formula of the mean and variance for the log-normal distribution on the log scale using the moments on the standard scale, to generate data with variance equal to 1 on the standard scale.

And then centre.

```r
data = ((rlnorm(meanlog = log(1/sqrt(2)), sdlog = sqrt((log(2))), n = 100000) - 1))

mean(data)
var(data)
```